# Java array split and matrix multiplication

Tags: java, multithreading

Can someone help me with this, please? I'm trying to do a matrix multiplication, using threads. This is what I have so far:
//updated

```
public class Multiplication {

public static final int NUM_OF_THREADS = 8;
public static final int MATRIX_SIZE = 1000;


public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int MatrixA[][] = matrixGenerator();
    int MatrixB[][] = matrixGenerator();

    int m1rows = MatrixA.length;

    int m1cols = MatrixA[0].length;

    int m2cols = MatrixB[0].length;

    int MatrixC[][] = new int[m1rows][m2cols];

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_OF_THREADS);
    for (int row1 = 0; row1 < m1rows; row1++) {
        for (int col1 = 0; col1 < m1cols; col1++) {
            pool.submit(new MultiplicationThreading(row1, col1, MatrixA, MatrixB, MatrixC));
        }
    }
    pool.shutdown();
    pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Calculated in "
            + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");

}

public static int[][] matrixGenerator() {

    int matrix[][] = new int[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];

    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = r.nextInt(10000);
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
}
```

//I have updated the code
I get better timings now. When using 2 threads I get 1.5k milliseconds and when I use 8 threads 1.3k milliseconds

Comment: You initialize the `thrd` array with `NUM_THREADS` elements. If `m1rows*m1cols` exceeds that value, you will get this problem.

Comment: If you only submit 1 thing to the thread pool, it doesn't matter how many threads there are in the pool (provided there is at least 1): each `Runnable` runs on just 1 thread. If you are finding this a lot faster, it's because you've not got the large overhead of creating new threads (which is very expensive).

Comment: Can I ask what should I change, please?

Comment: Split the work between multiple threads - like you did before. In the first code above, the innermost loop would have been executed in a separate thread.

Comment: I've updated the code. Can you have a look at it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize the `thrd` array with `NUM_THREADS == 9` elements. If `m1rows*m1cols` exceeds that value, you will get this problem, since you attempt to create more than 9 threads and assign them to elements of the array. (You are attempting to create 50 threads).

Two solutions:

1. Initialize `thrd = new Thread[m1rows*m1cols]`
2. Use a `List<Thread>`.

---

Note that you won't execute the threads in parallel, because you are calling `Thread.join()` immediately after calling `Thread.start()`. This just blocks the current thread until `thrd[threadcount]` finishes.

Move the `Thread.join()` calls into a separate loop, so the threads are all started before you call `join` on any of them.

```
    for (row = 0; row < m1rows; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < m1cols; col++) {
            // creating thread for multiplications
            thrd[threadcount] = new Thread(new MultiplicationThreading(row, col, MatrixA, MatrixB, MatrixC));
            thrd[threadcount].start(); //thread start
            threadcount++;
        }
    }
    for (Thread thread : thrd) {
      thread.join();
    }
```

Comment: you sir, are a star! thank you! it worked!
I will accept this answer as soon as the website allows me to do it

Comment: Also, note that this is better suited to using an `ExecutorService` rather than manually creating threads.

Comment: I have a question though..in this case, where am I using the NUM_OF_THREADS variable? :-/

Comment: Because I need to get the speedup depending on the number of threads. 
In this case, doesn't it depend on the size of the matrix?

Comment: If you want to limit the number of threads, definitely use an `ExecutorService`: submit your `new MultiplicationThreading(...)` to a fixed-size thread pool, e.g. created via `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_OF_THREADS)`.

Comment: Oh no. I'm completely new to them - no idea how they work. I will have a look online. But not sure how to implement it, though. could you please help me with this too?

Comment: I've tried something.. which works extremely faster than what I had previously. but If I change the number of threads, the timing is still the same - I've changed from 4 to 8 threads